# R base pie plot combined with other plots on plot grid does not hold proportions

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

When I draw base R `pie` plot it holds proportions and I see right circle.

But when I combine plots proportions are distorted. The circle becomes ellipse. How I can control figure proportions using `plot_grid` function? Should I use `viewport`?

The code and corresponding combined plots are below...

```
library(tidyverse)
library("grid")
library("ggplotify")
cyls<-mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl)
cyls$category=str_glue("Number of cylinders {cyls$cyl}")
p1 <- as.grob(~barplot(1:10))
p2 <- as.grob(~pie(cyls$n, labels = cyls$category))
p3 <- as.grob(function() plot(sin))
library(cowplot)
p6 <-as.grob(~{
  par(
    mar = c(0, 7, 0, 7)
  )
  pie(cyls$n, labels = cyls$category)
  #plot(sqrt)

})
plot_grid(plot_grid(p6), plot_grid(p1,p3), rel_heights = c(2,1), nrow=2, scale = c(1, 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution could be

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
pie(cyls$n, labels = cyls$category)
barplot(1:10)
plot(sin)
```

[image]

Using cowplot you can try

```
cyls$category=str_glue("Number\nof\ncylinders {cyls$cyl}")
plot_grid(p2, plot_grid(p1, p3),  nrow=2, rel_heights = c(0.8, 0.2))
# or
plot_grid(plot_grid(NULL, p2, NULL, nrow = 1, rel_widths =c(0.25,0.5,0.25)),
          plot_grid(p1, p3),  nrow=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I need to combine base R plot with ggplots. This is my question about. Your solution will work, but it is not that I need.

Comment: aha..and do you think I'm a magician? You provided this important information not in your question neither in the title, right? And your example plots aren't ggplots at all. No need to downvote. You can start with `plot_grid(p2, NULL, p1, p3,  nrow=2)`

Comment: This approach does not work and besides I need top plot in the center, but in this case it goes to the top left conner